# Magento 1.11.0 returning empty set for custom model getCollection()->getData()?

Tags: collection, sql, ee-1.11

Our extension uses a custom model for some data that we need to use. For CE Magento installs, (a la 1.6-1.8) this works fine, but in our client's 1.11 install this returns an empty set:

```
$mapping = Mage::getModel('syncer/mapping')->getCollection()->getData();
var_dump($mapping); // NULL
```

Any idea what's up with this?

I'm not very familiar with the Magento API code but by debugging this is what I found, if more code is relevant please let me know and I'l paste it here. I've tried searching for this problem but came fruitless.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for the Model call, its a third part extension... So teste you could make is...

```
get_class(Mage::getModel('syncer/mapping')->getCollection())
```

to see if it reaches this models collection class, if its ok the class, you can try this next:

```
Mage::getModel('syncer/mapping')->getCollection()->count()
```

this retrieves the number of results of the collection (it must bring the same number results from the table linked to this collection)

After this you can try

```
(string) Mage::getModel('syncer/mapping')->getCollection()->getSelect() 
or
Mage::getModel('syncer/mapping')->getCollection()->getSelect()->__toString()
```

to see the query and try it out in your db client